# Multi router network and IPv6 DHCP/RA issues - How to assign default routers?

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, ipv6, isc-dhcp

I've again got problems with our LAN. There are 4 WAN gateways all on the same subnet, all with 100M uplink. On IPv4 I advertise default routers using a ISC DHCP Server. On IPv6 there doesn't seem to be an default gateway option in DHCP - all is managed via router advertisements. But how do I specify which client should use which router - with SOHO routers ....

Routing all traffic over my DHCP box and redirecting it via ip6tables isn't an option, as the network has an 10GbE link between the sections and is highly trafficked.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Why would you have a flat network with four default gateways and limit which host can use which default gateway? This sounds like a very bad design to me.

Answer (score 1):

IPv6 doesn't provide options to force clients to use a specific gateway. Instead it let's clients make the choice themselves. You might be able to do some filtering on your network so the clients don't see the RAs from remote parts of the network, but this would be a hack.

The solution is to split your broadcast domain into separate networks. Use separate subnets on each of them, both for IPv4 and IPv6. You can use ARP proxy if you need to simulate the current situation of IPv4, but I would strongly recommend against that. Instead it's much better to fix the network architecture.

Comment: The reason that I don't use different VLANS is that there are 802.11f (WLAN roaming) capable access points across the area. This means every wireless client could join on every geographical location accessing it's own network. Also there's a central storage server, which has to be accessible by all clients but may only access the internet using one router.

The reason of not using different subnets is that some clients across the whole network access ressources on the storage server using Upnp and samba/cifs with netbios name resolution. Not all TVs can access these ressources using dns.

Comment: So the only solution at this time is to disable IPv6 accross the network?

Comment: It still sounds like a bad architecture. A combination of separate SSIDs, static addressing and routing for the server, WINS for name resolution etc. would give you a more scalable solution. I don't see how you could deploy IPv6 in your current setup.